# How can I open crontab from Bash and add a comment to a cron?

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, cron

Currently this is our scenario.

1. SSH into Node 1
2. sudo crontab -e
3. Change this `* * * * * /rsync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1` to `#* * * * * /rsync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1`
4. cd /var/www/www.site.com/public_html/
5. npm run prod
6. Wait for npm success
7. sudo crontab -e
8. Change this `#* * * * * /rsync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1` to `* * * * * /rsync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1`
9. Exit SSH

So each time we are deploying we are adding or removing a comment from the crontab and appending or removing the `#` before. It is time consuming so I wrote this script.

I only have one cron line.

(I am not bash expert)

```
#!/bin/bash

START_TIME=`date +%s`

# turn off rsync by deleting cron (from root user)
crontab -e -u root

# deploy to production node 1
npm run prod
sudo service varnish restart
END_TIME=`date +%s`

# turn on rsync by making the cron again
crontab -e -u root | { cat; echo "* * * * * /root/scripts/sync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1"; } | crontab -

echo -e ""
```

This is not working as it is just not adding a line nor finding and removing the code as I want. Anyone help?

I get this error:

`no crontab for root - using an empty one
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal` and it hangs..

Comment: Do you have other entries in the crontab?  If there is just the single entry that gives you a few more options.  Like just deleting the file when you want to stop it and recreating it when you want to start it.  There's also the possibility of depnding on the environment.  Putting a file in the /etc/cron.d/ folder that does your rsync job and then when you want to stop the file job just making the file hidden by moving it from /etc/cron.d/myjob to /etc/cron.d/.myjob

Comment: I think deleting the file and then adding it would be better - there are no other lines in the crontab list

Comment: @JeffRichards I updated my question

Comment: You may want to check [cron - When to Use Sudo with Crontab - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/817499/when-to-use-sudo-with-crontab). Do you really need it scheduled with root credentials?

Comment: I'm not so sure that crontab -e is going to accept it from the command line, usually it is spawning an editor, which would be why it hangs.  If you go the route of putting a file in /etc/cron.d/ then you can avoid needing to use the crontab program at all.  Then it's just file manipulation which you could do with echo "* * * * * USER /root/scripts/sync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1" > /etc/cron.d/myjob the only trick there is that cron.d requires a slightly different format which includes the user who the job did be run as.  See my alteration.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto for more

Comment: I think the problem is -- you can't do this in a script.. What state does `crontab -e -u root` leave the crontab editor in? (open). Your script should just hang here waiting for you to close the default editor you are attempting to edit the crontab in. Next `crontab -e -u root | { cat; echo "* * * * * /root/scripts/sync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1"; } | crontab -` is just crazy. You are trying to pipe an open crontab edit session -- I doubt that will ever work. Maybe I'm missing the obvious, but you can't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/etc/cron.d` as suggested by [@Jeff Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190834/jeff-richards).

Files in `/etc/cron.d` do not need the use of the `crontab` command to be updated.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -uex

START_TIME=$(date +%s)

# turn off rsync by deleting cron
sudo rm /etc/cron.d/www.site.com_sync

# deploy to production node 1
cd /var/www/www.site.com/public_html/
npm run prod
service varnish restart

END_TIME=$(date +%s)

# turn on rsync by making the cron again
echo '* * * * *  root  /root/scripts/sync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1' | sudo tee /etc/cron.d/www.site.com_sync
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the submission. What is `set -uex` and `sudo tee`

Comment: `u` exits on undefined variables. `e` exits on commands that fail. `x` shows what bash is executing, essentially debug.  `tee` writes stdin to a file and to stdout, so you can `sudo` write to a file without redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I am using for future people

```
#!/bin/bash
## DELETE THE RYSYNC COMMAND
sudo crontab -r -u root
( cd app/src ; gulp static-builder )
npm run prod
## RESTART VARNISH
sudo service varnish restart
## START THE RYSYNC COMMAND
(sudo crontab -u root -l; echo "* * * * * /root/scripts/sync.sh >>/dev/null 2>&1") | sudo crontab -u root -
```

I do not recommend it compared with the command suggestions by others; but for now, we will be using this.

I delete the cron entirely for that user. I then write the line again after deployment to production.